# How to assert a URL was not requested with HTTPretty

Tags: python, httpretty

How does one go about asserting that a target URL was never requested when using HTTPretty to intercept HTTP requests in Python unit tests?

Comment: Could you add some code to illustrate the problem?

Answer (score 0):

By default, if a request doesn't match any registered URI it goes through.

One solution would be to add a generic matcher using [*Matching regular expressions*](https://github.com/gabrielfalcao/HTTPretty#matching-regular-expressions) and making it failing.

```
>>> httpretty.register_uri(httpretty.GET,
...                        re.compile(".*"),
...                        status=500,
...                        body="Fail")
...
>>> requests.get("http://www.google.ch/")
<Response [200]>
>>> httpretty.activate()
>>> requests.get("http://www.google.ch/")
<Response [500]>
```

Of course, your application must fail in such cases. Another idea might be to use record.

Another idea would be to use `HTTPretty.record` and then analyze the produced file. But it feels a bit more complicated.